# Graphical Explanation

Tags: c, logic

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int c;  /* Present Character */
   int old_c; /* Previous Character */

   while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
      if (old_c == ' ' && c != ' ') {
         putchar(' ');
         putchar(c);
      } else if(c != ' ') {
         putchar(c);
      }
      old_c = c;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I don't really understand how this code works. This is a solution for the C The programming language exercise 1.9:

> > Exercise 1-9:
> >
> > Write a program to copy it's input to it's output, replacing each string of one or more blanks by a single blank.
> >
> > *The C Programming Language* 2nd edition,
> >             B. Kernighan and D. Ritchie, Prentice 
> >             Hall, page 20.

So here is my Problem

For example I type in as Input : `Hello  World\n`

is the `'\n'` not the last character ? save into `old_c : old_c = c;`

could someone please explain to me how to code works as I really want to learn the c programming language and programming. 
I am a very beginner;

Comment: Could you include the exercise text in the question?

Comment: The code above has an error as `old_c` is used when it is uninitialised.

Comment: To answer part of the question, if you type `Hello World\n` into the terminal, the `\n` won't be interpreted as a single newline character, it will be read in separately, so the last character is just `n`.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what the output of this program is, and what output you are expecting. Nor is it clear what the original problem is,

Answer (score 0):

This code does 9 things:

1. First, it declares some variables `c` and `old_c`,
2. Then it reads input from the keyboard into `c`.
3. After that, it checks to see if `old_c` is  and `c` is not .
4. If so, it prints a space and the character last pressed.
5. Otherwise, it just prints the character last pressed.
6. Then, `old_c` is set to `c`.
7. Jump to 2 until input is stopped (usually with CTRL+D or the enter key)
8. It then loads the return value (`0`, in this case),
9. and it exits with that return value.